# What is the $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}=$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> For 
>   $$f(x):=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
>   what is the $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}=$?

Is it just $1$?

Comment: I think that's correct (it's $\tanh(x)$)

Comment: Yes if domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x)=\tanh{x}$ which is continuous on the whole real line. Since $f^{\prime}(x)=1/\cosh^{2}{x}>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore,

$$\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)|=\lim_{x\longrightarrow +\infty}|f(x)|=1$$.

Answer (score 2):

$-1 < f(x) < 1$ for all real $x$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 1$, so yes it is $1$.